# Bootstraps form labels inside form inputs

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, label

Is there a way to place small form labels inside the form box that remain after user adds input? Inline form labels take up too much space.  I am trying to create forms that group tight like tables.

Comment: you should try showing what your problem or expected result so people can visualize problem and give solutions.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-infield-top-aligned-form-labels-are-quickest-to-scan

Answer (score 7):

You mean this? [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/k4nprtjj/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="leftNav" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group" id="holder"> <small id="label" for="input">Email address</small>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#holder {
    height: 50px;
}
#label {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ccc;
}
#input {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: @DevAntoine pro tip. Press ctrl + f then type "label".

Comment: pro tip. Learn what a label is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: In this example you are free to use label if you want. Otherwise, just copy and paste it like a normal person.